# Connect to Web Server using HTTPS from .NET Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, https

I'm totally new to SSL. I have .NET client that connect to Web Server (SOAP-based web Services) using HTTPS. Do I need to do anything extra at the .NET client app? Current, the server end-point URL that I use is already HTTPS, and it seems to work fine. However, when comparing to browser, a browser knows when it's HTTPS connection (the pad lock at address bar). So, how do I ensure that my .NET client is connect via HTTPS connection? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you *tried* ? And what is **not working** for you. Also post code snippets of what your are trying.

Comment: Show us some of the code for the ".net client app"